# I want to specify that on following area on google map we have a coverage I want to do this on android app

Tags: android, google-maps

Hello guys I am new in android.

http://www.att.com/maps/wireless-coverage.html

open this link and see a image of  coverage area of map

I want to do same thing in on android app ,I want to do draw same coverage area on map in android app  I am using google map api v2 in android app.

Thanks